# Debug Entity Framework error Column Name Cannot be Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using EF Core 5.0 and while trying to insert and update some entities i am getting error
The exception is of type DbUpdateException

An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
Column Name Cannot be Null

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    
}
```

Any way to know which related  Entity  is causing this exception

Since in my case my Entity Address got so many relations and most of them got Name property

Example: Address related to Country Continent County and all of these entities got Name property

So from exception can we get some more info on which entity name is missing

Comment: Does the stack trace give anything useful?

Comment: I would suggest you log the exception somewhere rather than just catching it and then ignoring it.

Comment: As presented, the error message is ambiguous/confusing. I don't think the error is "The name of the column cannot be null" - I think the error is "The column called [Name] is configured such that a value must be provided". Somewhere you're trying to update a non-null column to null. Finding which one would be relatively trivial if you enable logging, and set EnableSensitiveDatalogging - you'll get to see the parameter values the SQL is trying to save, and exactly which query is running when the error throws. `UPDATE Person SET name =@p27` and `@p27=NULL` in the logs will indicate which entity

Comment: In your Startup.cs, where you have `services.AddDbContextFactory<WhateverContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(...)` add these onto the end of the UseSqlServer call's closing parenthesis: `.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()` and `.LogTo(System.Console.WriteLine, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information)`

Comment: Managed to find the information after enable SensitiveDataLogging @CaiusJard

Comment: Good stuff! You can also write `#warning remove these settings when pushing to prod` So you get a compiler warning to remind you to take them out again or put them on an `#if DEBUG` block ..

Comment: Still I can't help but imagine how much time and energy they could save if they just add "Column Name on Table/Entity Foo" instead.  Such an easy win.